# Need to join three tables in MySQL and subtract total values from two with duplicates

Tags: mysql

So I have these three tables:

Table 1: business

```
+----------+----------+
| ID       | customer |
+----------+----------+
|    A     | NY       | 
|    B     | NJ       |
|    C     | CT       |
+----------+----------+
```

Table 2: 2014

```
+----------+----------+
| business | cost     |
+----------+----------+
|    A     | 10000    | 
|    A     | 5000     | 
|    B     | 3000     |
|    C     | 5000     |
+----------+----------+
```

Table 3: 2013

```
+----------+----------+
| business | cost     |
+----------+----------+
|    A     | 15000    | 
|    A     | 5000     | 
|    B     | 10000    |
|    C     | 2000     |
+----------+----------+
```

And I would like the following result:

```
+----------+----------+
| ID       | diff     |
+----------+----------+
|    A     | -5000    | 
|    B     | -7000    |
|    C     | 3000     |
+----------+----------+
```

Essentially, I am trying to build a query that uses the business name in the first table to identify the values I want to sum and subtract in the second and third tables.

This is what I am trying, but it is returning the wrong values:

```
SELECT ID, sum(2014.cost)-sum(2013.cost) as diff
FROM business 
JOIN 2014 ON business.ID = 2014.business 
JOIN 2013 ON business.ID = 2013.business 
GROUP BY ID;
```

Comment: What seems to be a problem? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Good question. I'll update the problem.

Comment: Did you actually run your query against the data in your post?

Comment: The query seems to work OK. What output were you hoping to get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your join is adding unnecessary numbers to some of the columns, you need to tweak your sql for the correct result;

```
SELECT ID, 
       (SELECT SUM(cost) FROM 2014 WHERE business = ID)
        -(SELECT SUM(cost) FROM 2013 WHERE business = ID) AS diff
FROM business 
GROUP BY ID;
```